# find the index from the exists value (check if) dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I am using python-3.x and I would like to check if the value exists or not in the dictionary **if it exists then I want to find and print the index number of that value in the dictionary**.

here an example of my code:

```
# import numpy
import numpy as np

# my first array
my_array_1 = np.array([[ 1  , 2  , 3  ],
                       [ 32 , 42 , 11 ],
                       [ 9  , 21 , 22 ],
                       [ 9  , 21 , 22 ],
                       [ 9  , 21 , 22 ],
                       [ 32 , 42 , 11 ],
                       [ 1  , 2  , 3  ]])


# here I want to find the unique values from my_array_1
indx = np.unique(my_array_1, return_index=True, return_counts= True,axis=0)


#save the result to dictionary
dic_t= {"my_array_uniq":indx[0],
       "counts":indx[1]}


# my 2nd array
my_array_2 = np.array([[ 1  , 2   , 3  ],
                       [ 32 , 422 , 11 ],
                       [ 9  , 221 , 22 ],
                       [ 9  , 221 , 22 ],
                       [ 9  , 21  , 22 ],
                       [ 32 , 242 , 11 ],
                       [ 1  , 22  , 3] ])



for i in range (len(my_array_2)):

# here I want to check if the vlue exist or not


    if any((my_array_2[i] == j).all() for j in dic_t["my_array_uniq"]):

######(if it exists print the index number of the existing vlue in dic_t["my_array_uniq"])######

        print (50*"*", i, "Yes")
        print (my_array_2[i], "\n")
        print (dic_t["my_array_uniq"])

    else:
        print (50*"*", i, "No")        
        dic_t["my_array_uniq"] = np.vstack((dic_t["my_array_uniq"], my_array_2[i]))
```

All I need is the index number I did my best to find the right way but none of them works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the line that tests whether the element exists, you do not keep the index where it is found.

You should use enumerate to process both the index and the value from a list:

```
for i, a in enumerate(my_array_2):

# here I want to check if the vlue exist or not

    ix = [k for k,j in enumerate(dic_t["my_array_uniq"]) if (a == j).all()]    
    if ix:

######(if it exists print the index number of the existing vlue in dic_t["my_array_uniq"])######

        print (50*"*", i, "Yes", "at", ix[0])
        print (my_array_2[i], "\n")
        print (dic_t["my_array_uniq"])

    else:
        print (50*"*", i, "No")        
        dic_t["my_array_uniq"] = np.vstack((dic_t["my_array_uniq"], my_array_2[i]))
```

Comment: I get this **error** `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` from this line `for i, a in my_array_2:` I am not sure way

Comment: My bad it should be `enumerate(my_array_2)`. Post edited. (I did some test with variable names different than yours, and wrongly merged everything :-( )

Comment: Great Many thanks for the help I will read about enumerate :)